# PHP SQL Server Insert issue

Tags: php, sql-server

The following statement runs fine in the MS SQL server management studio.  However when I try to execute via PHP the insert does not occur and no errors are returned.  I know my connection is valid, all my select statements return properly.  What am I missing?

```
DECLARE @id bigint; SET @id = (SELECT MAX(application_track_id) + 1 FROM application_track_data); INSERT INTO application_track_data (application_track_id,user_id, action_key, action, ip_address, session_id, application) VALUES (@id,1,'584','login','192.168.37.60','05sn3618p61dvmml6pkefuteg2','akamata');
```

Here is the code I am using to execute the sql.

```
$result = mssql_query($sql);
if(!$result)
{
print "Error:" . mssql_get_last_message();
}
else
print "Success";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have it working.  I switched to using the SQL server driver provided by Microsoft available here http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=61BF87E0-D031-466B-B09A-6597C21A2E2A&displaylang=en .

Apparently the mssql driver cannot work with certain data types, like bigint.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to put this in a procedure.  Since you have multiple commands in your SQL statement I believe most db drivers only can call a single statement (or single T-SQL statement).  So if you need multiple things to happen turn it into a stored procedure or execute each individual statement based on return value etc.

UPDATE: Try this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-next-result.php

I guess it does allow multiple queries but you need to get the right one.  There are also some db libraries that have a *_query_multiple function but only in the mysqli libraries or maxdb libraries.

Comment: Ok, I put it in a stored procedure.  Now I get the following error: Error converting data type varchar to numeric.  The SP runs fine from the Management Studio.  The only thing that I see with the table structure is that one of the columns is a bigint.  Will that cause an issue.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you are running with autocommit off, and not committing the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of activity really should be in a stored procedure. Easier to manage and easier to call from php.  You also need to commit those changes everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Try the insert statement alone.  If that works then you know having multiple statements is causing an error (and you'll need to replace your queries with a stored procedure).  If it fails then jsight is right, it's a problem with autocommit.

Personally I'd place my bet with the multiple statements, but this should give you a route to determine the root cause (it's possible both are a problem).

Comment: If I run the insert statement by itself. I get "Error converting datatype varchar to numeric".  If i reduce the insert statement to the only required field I still get the error.  Will a bigint data type cause an issue?